# AWS Lambda function initiated twice from cloudwatch, runs successfully only once, why are errors not logged

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using cloudwatch event to trigger a labmda when a new ecs instance starts up.

I'm a bit mystified by the logs, it looks like the function is called then fails silently and then called again and runs successfully with the same event input.

I understand that lambda functions can be called multiple times from cloudwatch for the same event because the delivery contract is at least once and I plan on making changes to the function so it's idempotent.

My question is, what is happening when it's called the first time and just stops running?

**More info based on Jarmod's question**

The first time the function is called only the following tags are available:

```
'Tags': [{'Key': 'aws:ec2launchtemplate:id', 'ResourceId': 'i-0a0500abc17bc7e9e', 'ResourceType': 'instance', 'Value': 'lt-01e5585a011e48b97'}]
```

This means my code was failing on the following line:

```
if 'torres' in ec2_response['Tags'][0]['Value']
```

Since when I set the filter to only get the Name tag, the tags were coming back empty the first time. I'm assuming that the lambda was being re-run based on [Lambda re-run documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html) and the second time it's called the Name tag is there and everything is great.

So my question becomes, why am I not getting an error in my lambda logs?

Here's the log output:

```
2019-01-01 11:34:46
START RequestId: 63190c9b-0dd2-11e9-b6ed-256f780af4a8 Version: $LATEST
Event: {'version': '0', 'id': '12f0dc8e-2c49-be57-823f-ab6229b12804', 
'detail-type': 'EC2 Instance State-change Notification', 'source': 
'aws.ec2', 'account': '701704546303', 'time': '2019-01-01T14:34:46Z', 
'region': 'us-west-2', 'resources': ['arn:aws:ec2:us-west- 
2:701704546303:instance/i-0a4af714ff4396d55'], 'detail': {'instance-id': 'i-0a4af714ff4396d55', 'state': 'running'}}
, Context: <bootstrap.LambdaContext object at 0x7fc8f40525f8>
Making ec2 name request
END RequestId: 63190c9b-0dd2-11e9-b6ed-256f780af4a8
REPORT RequestId: 63190c9b-0dd2-11e9-b6ed-256f780af4a8 Duration: 366.46 ms  Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 39 MB  

2019-01-01 11:35:46
START RequestId: 63190c9b-0dd2-11e9-b6ed-256f780af4a8 Version: $LATEST
Event: {'version': '0', 'id': '12f0dc8e-2c49-be57-823f-ab6229b12804',                     
'detail-type': 'EC2 Instance State-change Notification', 'source': 
'aws.ec2', 'account': '701704546303', 'time': '2019-01-01T14:34:46Z', 
'region': 'us-west-2', 'resources': ['arn:aws:ec2:us-west- 
2:701704546303:instance/i-0a4af714ff4396d55'], 'detail': {'instance- 
id': 'i-0a4af714ff4396d55', 'state': 'running'}}
, Context: <bootstrap.LambdaContext object at 0x7fc8f724ca58>
Making ec2 name request
torres instance, starting ecs task
END RequestId: 63190c9b-0dd2-11e9-b6ed-256f780af4a8
REPORT RequestId: 63190c9b-0dd2-11e9-b6ed-256f780af4a8  Duration: 1022.97 ms    Billed Duration: 1100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB    Max Memory Used: 40 MB
```

Here's the function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('Event: {}\n, Context: {}'.format(event, context))
    if event['detail-type'] != 'EC2 Instance State-change Notification':
        print('Wrong event detail-type')
        ret = {
            'status': 'Wrong event detail-type'
        }
        print(event)
    else:
        print('Making ec2 name request')
        ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
        try:
            ec2_response = ec2_client.describe_tags(
                Filters=[
                    {
                        'Name': 'resource-id',
                        'Values': [
                            event['detail']['instance-id']
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'key',
                        'Values': [
                            'Name'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print('Failed ec2 call')
            print(e)
            raise e
        if 'torres' in ec2_response['Tags'][0]['Value']:
            print('torres instance, starting ecs task')
            ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs', region_name='us-west-2')
            try:
                ecs_response = ecs_client.run_task(
                    cluster='torres',
                    taskDefinition='torres:16'
                )
            except Exception as e:
                print('Failed ecs call')
                print(e)
                raise e
            task_definition_arns = [t['taskDefinitionArn'] for t in ecs_response['tasks']]
            ecs_status = ecs_response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']

            ret = {
                'task_definition_arns': task_definition_arns,
                'ecs_status': ecs_status
            }
        else:
            print('Wrong instance')
            ret = {
                'status': 'Wrong instance',
                'event': event
            }

    return ret
```

Comment: Is that the complete lambda function? I cant find the `making asg lifecycle hook call` output... - And can you make sure, that a Lambda timeout is not the issue? This is usually my first impulse when something in a possible cold-start-situation fails ;-)

Comment: What does ec2_response contain in the first case? Does it actually have any valid content with tags?

Comment: @Maurice - that was from an earlier version of it, I removed that from the logs it doesn't affect the problem.

Comment: @jarmod - you nailed it, the tag isn't there. I'm not sure why the exception didn't make it to the log though. I guess that's the better question now :)

Comment: You could include a try/catch around the API calls and log the exception. I'm assuming that the root cause is a timing issue - the ECS resource is launched before the tags are applied (launch and tag are not a single atomic operation presumably) and your Lambda function is being invoked after the launch but before the application of tags (and then the automatic Lambda retry is happening *after* the application of tags, so your Lambda works second time around).

Comment: According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-exceptions.html the error of me looking for a dictionary key that's not there should be showing up in the logs, but it's not. That's the new mystery, which sounds like an AWS issue? I know how I'll work around this, but I'm curious about why the logging isn't working as expected.

Comment: @sshevlyagin This is apparently an [Issue with the Python 3.7 Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002903/aws-lambda-python-3-7-runtime-exception-logging) - switch back to 3.6 and you should see the exception.